# display string on value change (higher value more characters)

Tags: java, android

I was thinking about dynamically displaying text and I've got one question.

I have very long string .... few thousand characters or more. And I have value that's incremented over time. Now at the beginning when the value is 0 I want nothing to be shown (easy so far :)) but as the value increases i want the string to slowly appear (let's say 50 per one 'incrementation') ... it would be ideal to achieve effect of typing.

My solution was to declare empty string in onCreate method

```
string displayedText = "";
```

Then i'd call the display function in my handler that awaits for the incrementation

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case VALUE_CHANGE:
                value = (int)msg.arg1;  // get value from message
                mValueView.setText("" + mStepValue); // display value on screen
                //here call the function to display text
                break;

            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

This so far is working ... now the problematic (for me) part with displaying text. The value can be sent with different time from 1 second between incrementing to 10 seconds (it's random when the value changes)

Comment: what do you do inside display text method? Where is the problem here?

Comment: well i don't have the display text method yet since i don't know how to extract one character at a time from string to add to displayed text

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more clear? Now you are saying you have issues on extracting text. Your question subject says a different thing.

Comment: i have a text that i want to display more and more as the value grows, so for example value is 0 i can see 0 character from text when value is 2 i can see 60 characters from text when value is 4 i can see 120 characters from text etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring` method to extract from the complete `String` .

```
private String extractText(String input, int length)
{
 return input.substring(0, length - 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks :) and sorry for confusing with explanation of problem ... english is not my native tounge

Answer (score 0):

Use delayed message. Don't have a hard load of UI.

```
private boolean isCanChange = true;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case VALUE_CHANGE:
                value = (int)msg.arg1;  // get value from message
                mValueView.setText("" + mStepValue); // display value on screen
                //here call the function to display text
                isCanChange = true;
                break;

            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
while(isParsingRunning) {
    //running parse thread
    if(isCanChange) {
        isCanChange = false;
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(VALUE_CHANGE, 1000);// update every second 
    }
}
```

Decrease update speed

```
public void parseDocument(...)
{
    long startParsingTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(isParsing) {
         // parse
        if(isCanChange) {
            isCanChange = false;
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(VALUE_CHANGE, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startParsingTime)/1000);// update every second 
        }
    }
}
```

Note : may be you need to cast. I haven't any IDE on my hands.

Comment: i got a bit confused with explaining the problem ... recieving messages works :)